# Developed android application cannot connect to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, android, eclipse

I am developing an app with eclipse. I tried to store the data that key in by user into database in phpmyadmin. Unfortunately, after the user has clicked on submit button, there is no response and data is not stored in my database.

Here is my java file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

public class UserRegister extends Activity {

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
RadioButton button1;
RadioButton button2;
Button button3;
int success = 0;

private static String url_register_user = "http://10.20.92.81/database/add_user.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_register);

    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTextBox);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameTextBox);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailTextBox);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwTextBox);

    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regSubmitButton);

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String username = inputUsername.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (name.contentEquals("")||username.contentEquals("")||email.contentEquals("")||password.contentEquals(""))
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserRegister.this);


                builder.setMessage(R.string.nullAlert)
                   .setTitle(R.string.alertTitle);

                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   }
               });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
            }

            // creating new product in background thread
                RegisterNewUser();  
        }
    });
}


   public void RegisterNewUser()
   {
   try
   {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String username = inputUsername.getText().toString();
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register_user,
                "GET", params);

        // check log cat for response
        Log.d("Send Notification", json.toString());

        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1)
        {
            // successfully created product
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentLogin.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        else
        {
            // failed to register

        }
   }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

   @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }
}
```

my php file:

```
<?php
$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();


if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {

$name = $_GET['name'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];


// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO register(name, username, email, password) VALUES('$name', '$username', '$email', '$password')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered to MEMS.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} 
else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

the log cat is as follows:

```
11-25 10:37:46.772: I/Choreographer(638): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, follow Java naming conventions and keep your method names starting with a lower case.

Secondly, you must be getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, because you're performing the blocking Network operation on your UI thread. You do that and you're gonna have a bad time.

Put all your network code within an async task, or at least a separate thread.

Comment: thank you very much.. finally i solved the problem that i faced for almost three weeks.. thanks! =)

Comment: If you get the solution Let me know please.How to save the details in php myadmin mysql database side.please help me